# $M||\textbf{x}||$ $\leq$ $f(\textbf{x})$?

Tags: calculus

Given a function $f$: $(V, || \circ ||_{\infty})$ $\rightarrow$ $(\mathbb{R}, |\circ |)$

how can you then show that there exists  $M$ $>$ $0$ such that $M||\textbf{x}||$ $\leq$ $f(\textbf{x})$ for every $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}$?

I thought maybe that it could be done by showing that $f$ is a bounded linear operator but i'm not sure that it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can just take $\alpha=\min\{f(y)\,:\,\lVert y\rVert=1\}$ because $S^{m-1}$ is compact.

Comment: What is $S^{m-1}$? and why does it being compact make it work?

Comment: $S^{m-1}=\{y\in\Bbb R^m\,:\, \lVert y\rVert=1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert #1 \right\Vert}$
Homogenuity of a function gives $f(sx) = |s|f(x)$ for all $s \in \R$ and all $x\in \R^n$.
We have
$$
f(x) = \norm{x}f\left(\frac{x}{\norm{x}}\right)
$$
for all $x \in \R^n\setminus\{0\}$. Therefore, if we find $a > 0$ such that $f(x/\norm{x}) \geq a$ for all $x \in \R^n\setminus\{0\}$, we are done. But as we know,
$$
\norm{\frac{x}{\norm{x}}}
= \frac{1}{\norm{x}}\norm{x}
= 1
$$
This is equivalent that we have to find $a > 0$ such that $f(y) \geq a $ for all $\norm{y} = 1$, that is,
$$
a \geq c= \min_{\norm{y}=1}f(y) > 0
$$
Hence, the smallest such coefficient is $c$.

Comment: how do we know that $||x/||x|| ||$ is 1?

Comment: @casper54 Because $x$ is a vector, whereas $\Vert x \Vert$ is a scalar. I augmented the part in the answer.